# Multiplying pop'd integers

Tags: java, stack, tail-recursion

I am writing a piece of code to pop from the Stack and multiply. I know that I can print my pop'd integers, but how do I keep track of a pop'd integer if I pop another one?

I'm trying to write a for loop with a basic counter to pop the top integer, save it to a variable, and multiply that variable to the next popped integer.

```
static LStack<Integer> stack = new LStack<Integer>();


        static public void main (String[] args) 
        { 


        stack.push(1);
        stack.push(2);
        stack.push(3);
        stack.push(4);

        for(int i = stack.length(); i <= 0; i++) {
            stack.pop();


        }

        }
```

Comment: Do you have to use a `for` loop?

Comment: I do not, i was just trying things out, I think I found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier/clearer to use a `while` loop:

```
int result = stack.pop();
while (!stack.empty()) {
    result *= stack.pop();
}
```

If you have to use a `for` loop:

```
int result;
for (result = stack.pop(); !stack.empty();)
    result *= stack.pop();
}
```

Regardless, the key is to initialise your end result with the top value on the stack, then multiply it by each element that you pop off the stack.

Answer (score 0):

```
static LStack<Integer> stack = new LStack<Integer>();
```

/* fact() function */

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        stack.push(1);
        stack.push(2);
        stack.push(3);
        stack.push(4);




      System.out.println(calc(stack.pop()));
    }

    public static long calc(long n) {
        if (n <= 1)
            return 1;
        else
            return n * calc(n - 1);

}

    }
```

This is what I ended up using, implemented the calculator from another post, it seems to work and allows me to push additional integers on. Thank you for your time everyone!